# Why is there something appearing in my textbox in Ruby on Rails and NoMethod Error undefined method 'each'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, textbox, nomethoderror

So, I'm a newbie in Ruby on Rails and I've created two classes, the Author controller class and Book controller class. Authors have books and each Book is connected to an author.

**Author model**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books
    validates_presence_of :genres
    validates_presence_of :name
end
```

**Book model**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    #Validations
    validates_presence_of :review
    validates_presence_of :title

    #Associations
    belongs_to :author
end
```

But when I try to add an Author the Book text box already has something inside.

**TEXTBOX**

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Book:0x007fc715555eb8>
```

I'm particularly confused because I haven't edited a single bit of the scaffold created new.html.erb for the author class--it's directly from rendering the 'form' which I haven't touched either and so I'm not even sure where that is and what's going wrong.

**Author _form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@author) do |f| %>
  <% if @author.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@author.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this author from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @author.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :genres %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :genres %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :books %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :books %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

And even after I fill in the data and hit send this is what shows up in my terminal (I'm using Postgresql to localhost)

**TERMINAL**

```
Started POST "/authors" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-23 17:05:11 -0500
Processing by AuthorsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LdpFtn0Tni9Qyu7jg3Zk3I3n+5EzCUeXelyifJhV460=", "author"=>{"name"=>"Harper Lee", "genres"=>"Fiction", "books"=>"To Kill A Mockingbird"}, "commit"=>"Create Author"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for "To Kill A Mockingbird":String):
  app/controllers/authors_controller.rb:27:in `create'

  Rendered /Users/Acorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@librarydata/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (22.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/Acorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@librarydata/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/Acorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@mlibrarydata/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/Acorn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@librarydata/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (35.7ms)
```

Which is confusing because I have no 'each' function anywhere I'm aware of.

**authors_controller.rb create function**

```
  # POST /authors
  # POST /authors.json
  def create
    @author = Author.new(author_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.save
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I assume that something is going wrong in the book class? How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your full form (which I assume is the `author` form) as well as the two models?

Also, in your create method, why do you have `@author = Author.new(author_params)` as opposed to `@author = Author.new(params[:author])`

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I updated the post. And uhm haha I'm not really sure? The scaffold generator make that @author = Author.new(author_params) so I assumed that was correct.

Comment: Oh ok. I'll take a look. In the mean time, what version of rails are you using?

Comment: So, what are you trying to accomplish? A) Are there existing books that you are going to assign to an `author` or, B) When an `author` is created do you want it to also create a new `book` with what is in the `books` field?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is answered nicely here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16999870/1775803](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16999870/1775803)

Comment: I'm using rails 4.0.3 and to be honest both A and B? A book is not required for a new 'author' but if there is a 'book' then it also creates a new 'book'. 'Books' can be created without 'authors' and will be a drop down menu for you to choose the 'author' so if the 'author' doesn't exist yet then you have to create the 'author' first. So the 'author' is the parent and the 'books' are the children. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ooooh! Thanks so much! I'll try implementing it!

Comment: Uh, I tried switching to '@author=Author.new(params[:author]) and it said 'ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError'

Comment: Yeah, if you are using rails 4 the scaffolding is correct. Stick with `author_params`. Additionally, that answer in the link I posted is for rails 3, rails 4 may have a slightly different way of doing it. Try looking for "rails 4 has_many :through tutorial" or something to that effect if you get stuck.