# Has_many to Has_many scheduling problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activerecord-relation

I have two models. One model is LessonHours, which is responsible for guiding the school classes. This model has weekday, start time and end time fields. The school's admin will register each lesson hour. For example, on monday, there'll be 5 classes, beginning at 8 AM, 8:50 AM, 9:40 AM and 10:30 AM. There'll be a register for each class.

The other model I have is the Teacher model. When we register the teacher, I need to tell the application what is his availability. So I need to show all Lesson Hours, divided by weekdays, so the admin can check its avaiability (ex: monday: 8 AM, 8:50 AM, tuesday: 10:30 AM, etc)

What's the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can be achieved by has_many :through Association concept

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :schedules
 has_many :lesson_hours, through: :schedules
end

class Schedules < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :teacher
 belongs_to :lesson_hour
end

class LessonHour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schedules
  has_many :teachers, through: :schedules
end
```

For more example please refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Yeah, but how could I achieve this in my form view?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999292/examples-of-new-create-actions-for-has-many-through-associations-nested

Comment: It's not working at all. I don't know how to display it in my view. I need checkboxes so the admin can check each schedule available.

Comment: Can you explain or attach image how you want to display in view?